Why is Hawaiian Earring Sequentially Compact?
I am not looking for a really formal proof, but I remember the reasoning was based on the fact that a subsequence can be found on one of the circles. However I cannot justify this and I don't have any ideas as to why this subsequence converges. So I would appreciate any help regarding this problem.
Also, Hawaiian Earring is considered to be like what is shown below:

Edit: I know this can be shown using Heine-Borel theorem, but I want to show that every sequence has a convergent subsequence in this set.

What do you mean by “if there were only one circle containing circles”? Like, if we just restrict to the left half of the picture? You get exactly the same space that way, so it doesn’t really matter.

@SassatelliGiulio Thanks, but here I don't want to use Heine-Borel theorem

@DavidGao Thanks for mentioning this. I remember there were some discussions about this in the class, but now I guess that wasn't something special. I'll edit my question.

Without Heine-Borel it will be impossible unless you invoke the (non-trivial) fact that each sequence in a  circle has a convergent subsequence.

Take any infinite sequence $(x_n)$ in the space.
Suppose that $x_n$ lie on arbitrarily small circles. Then taking a subsequence of the $x_n$ such that $x_{n+1}$ always lies on a smaller circle than $x_n$, this converges to 0.
If this is not the case, then the $x_n$ lie on only finitely many circles, but since the sequence is infinite, there must be some circle which contains infinitely many $x_n$. Restricting our attention to this circle, we know that this contains a convergent subsequence because the circle is sequentially compact. This can be seen by the same proof as in Bolzano-Weierstrass.

"This can be seen by the same proof as in Bolzano-Weierstrass." By this, you mean since the sequence is trapped in a circle, it is bounded in $\mathbb{R^2}$ and therefore has a convergent subsequence?

@MrAmbiguneDL Essentially yes. Just like how you prove Bolzano-Weierstrass on an interval by bisecting the interval, we can do it on a circle by bisecting circular arcs. You know that infinitely many points lie on either the right or left semicircle, and then on one of the quarter circles etc., and taking the endpoints of each arc this sequence converges.

@MrAmbiguneDL If you're willing to accept the "subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$" argument, you could just use it directly on the Hawaiian Earring itself.

@MartianInvader thanks, you are right. They meant the idea of the proof and not the theorem itself. I misunderstood.
